# Select a feature and show all its neighbor with different color

Tags: qgis, color

I want to select a feature and show itself in specific color, at the same time I want to show all its neighbor in another color, by this way I can check the neighbor relation clearly. My code is as the following, but if I click a feature many times, then the color will become very strange. What's wrong with code?

```
from qgis.gui import QgsHighlight
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QColor

laver = iface.activeLayer()
laver.removeSelection()
source_fid = '[% $id %]'
source_feature = laver.getFeature(int(source_fid))
h = QgsHighlight(iface.mapCanvas(),source_feature,laver)
h.setColor(QColor('#61DED0'))
tmp = source_feature['neighhex']
neighhex = tmp.split('|')
features = laver.getFeatures()
neighbors_fid = [f.id()for f in features if f['gcihex'] in neighhex]
laver.select(neighbors_fid)
iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor(QColor('black'))
```

in the layer we have gcihex and neighhex, gcihex can be unique id for each feature in the layer and neighhex include several gcihex separated by|,neighhex is used to show which features are neighbors of current feature. when we select one feature, we will highlight selected feature, then all the features included in neighhex item will be selected and change to another special color. we can clearly know the neighbor relation between different features by clicking one feature.

now my question is how I can backup current color of each selected features, then I can revert all color setting for previously selected feature and its neighbors when I click another new feature.

Comment: It is likely you will need to provide some more information before anyone can help you. For example, what is contained in the `neighhex` and `gcihex` fields? Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: my data are as the following, gcihex can be treated as a key id of features, and neighhex can be used to used to identify which features are neighbor of this featuregci gcihex neighhex Longitude Latitude Height Azimuth
163867623 9C46BE7 9C46BE8|9C46BE9 125.0136319 11.2040826 50 340
163867624 9C46BE8 9C46BE7|9C46BE9 125.0136319 11.2040826 50 60
163867625 9C46BE9 9C46BE7|9C46BE8 125.0136319 11.2040826 50 220
when I click a feature, want to to hight it with a different color, at the same time I want to hilight all its neighbor with another color.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @WenhuaKong - keep in mind that it is almost always best to edit the question, rather than provide the extra information in the comments.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the colour becoming strange? A screenshot or a gif would help a great deal. Bear in mind you are not removing your highlight (at least not in the code posted here), so by clicking multiple times you are stacking highlights on top of each other (perhaps that explains the colour issue?).

It would be good to append any generated highlights to a list and then iterate through and remove them at the beginning of the code (similar to you do with the `layer.removeSelection()`. E.g.: `for highlight in highlight_list: iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(highlight)`.